# PL/SQL: I get the error "Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & - + /"

Tags: oracle, plsql

My code:

```
create table dep_emp_ast(
cod_dep number(3),
cod_ang number(3));



declare
  type tab_imb is table of dept_ast.department_id%type;
  t tab_imb:=tab_imb();
  v_ang emp_ast.employee_id%type;
begin
  select distinct department_id
  bulk collect into t
  from dept_ast;
    forall i in 1..t.count 
    for j in (select employee_id
                      from emp_ast
                      where department_id=t(i)) loop
      insert into dep_emp_ast
      values(t(i),j.employee_id);
      exit when sql%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line('Au fost introdusi '||sql%bulk_rowcount(i));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Apparently I cannot have the for statement inside the forall statement, but I need the forall statement so that I can use the sql%bulk_collect so that I can print the number of rows inserted. How do I solve this right? Basically I saved all the department_ids in a nested table and with the for statement I get all the employees for each department and insert the employee id along with the department id in my dep_emp_ast table.

I also get the error

> Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static member constructor map

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to switch from `FORALL` to `FOR`.

---

Or, simplify code and avoid inner loop entirely as it doesn't do anything smart; yes, you'll lose `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` call, but it is pretty much useless anywhere but in tools that support it. End users won't ever see it (in their e.g. Apex or Forms or ... applications).

So:

```
begin
  select distinct department_id
  bulk collect into t
  from dept_ast;
  
  forall i in 1..t.count 
    insert into dep_emp_ast
      select a.department_id,
             a.employee_id
        from emp_ast a
        where a.department_id = t(i);
end;
```